# Plane not following NURBS curve (path) properly

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, curve-modifier, nurbs-surface

so I was trying to follow a [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GN_VRjLRP-M) on how to create a track for Assetto Corsa PC, where the map is created via Blender and the game's SDK. I have a path that is a NURBS curve, which is the roadmap / layout that I want - this is where the tutorial shows the use of a curve & array modifier to apply a plane to this curve. This has not worked for me and after a few hours of following suggestions from similar issues on these forums has yet to work. Find some screenshots below of this and an attached .blend file; any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: This shows the NURBS curve / path for the roads]
^ This shows the NURBS curve / path for the roads

[image: This shows the plane which is supposed to align with the path]
^ This shows the plane which is supposed to align with the path

[A copy of my .blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BgV2ntlCLTdknXloYA9SpApYbeV6EVmK/view?usp=sharing) (I couldn't figure out how to upload it to the actual page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The origin of both your object and the curve must be at the exact same location, so select the curve, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected* and select your object and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor*.